# Unity Space Shooter tutorial : CS 1526 ,1525 error in unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

**error CS1525**: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting`;'
 **error CS1526**: A new expression requires () or [] after type

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public float xMax, xMin, zMax, zMin;
    public float speed ;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {     
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement* speed;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3 (          
            Mathf(GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().position.x, xMax, xMin),
            0.0f,
            Mathf(GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().position.z, zMax, zMin)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().position.z` to mean? In particular, the `.` after `GetComponent` and before `<Rigidbody>` looks very suspicious to me. (It also looks to me like you should be calling `GetComponent` once...)

Comment: So exactly what should i do !

Comment: Well you could just delete that `.`... but you'd be better off declaring a local variable: `var body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); body.position = new Vector3(Mathf(body.position.x, xMax, xMin), 0.0f, Mathf(body.position.z, zMax, zMin));`

Comment: I doubt he has his own Mathf function and he's using Mathf namespace incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here. First of all there is `GetComponent.<Rigidbody>()`. The `.` there is wrong. The call should simply be

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

And keep in mind that any `GetComponent()` call is fairly expensive. So calling it multiple times is not just unnecessary, but can be really costly. Especially so if you do it within `Update()` or anything that gets called on a per frame basis. If you're going to reference a component often, store it.

So you would end up with something like

```
Rigidbody rigid_body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); //Perhaps once on Start()
```

and then later on

```
Vector3 current_position = rigid_body.position;
rigid_body.position = new Vector3 ( Mathf(current_position.x, xMax, xMin),
                                    0.0f,
                                    Mathf(current_position.z, zMax, zMin)
                                  );
```

And perhaps I'm wrong, but I think you really are trying to clamp your positional values? In that case the call would be

```
 Mathf.Clamp(current_position.x, xMax, xMin)
```

so make sure to have a look at that as well.

**Note:**

Based on some of the mistakes and comments I think you may be looking at the documentation, but for the wrong language. The documentation site is great like that.

Make sure that the documentation's language is set appropriately. You can do so at the top right.

[image]

That would explain some of the "mistakes" you made and is an easy trap to fall into.

Comment: Yah it solved many of the problems but still there is one more error message . I am a newbie to unity and c# :(   error CS0246: The type or namespace name `RigidBody' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Ah, typo. It should be Rigidbody. Not RigidBody.

Comment: error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `ferror CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments
error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected                                                       Error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected !error CS0103: The name `rigid_body' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Unity Documentation   GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().position = Vector3.zero;

Comment: Show me where the documentation says that. And `rigid_body` is something you have to create to store a reference to your Rigidbody. At this point I would suggest you try to find a good book (online or otherwise) for the C# language. It seems you're having trouble with some of the basics of the language.

Comment: Are you're looking at the Javascript view? See the top right. Go to the C# view. That's the language you're saying you use.

Comment: If you copy past the C# version of that code, it should just work. `rigidbody` is a property of a MonoBehaviour. But keep in mind that underwater it does call `GetComponent`.

Comment: @Bart since unity 5, rigidibody is no longer a property of MonoBehaviour. But i love your answer and you really helped the guy when many would not.

Comment: You are of course absolutely right @Catwood. Old habits die hard. I should have caught that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You guy's saved the day!.
        Here is the Code :D

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{  public Rigidbody rb;
public float xMax,xMin,zMax,zMin;
public float velocity;
void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.velocity = movement*velocity;
    Vector3 current_position = rb.position;
    rb.position = new Vector3 ( Mathf.Clamp(current_position.x,xMin,xMax),
                                       0.0f,
                               Mathf.Clamp(current_position.z, zMin, zMax)
                                       );
                      }
                   }
```